# Core Data - One-to-many relationship getting nil

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, relationship, one-to-many

Can someone help me?
Why this doesn’t work?

```
func appendTrainingDay() {
        let dayLabel = dayName.text
        let dayEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDay", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
        let newTrainingDay = TrainingDay(entity: dayEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
        newTrainingDay.day = dayName.text

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)

        if let err = error {
            var status = err.localizedFailureReason
            println("\(status)")
        } else {
            println("Training day:\(dayName.text)")
    }
}
```

-> Save a day

```
func appendTrainingDetailsToArray () {
        let nameLabel = exerciseName.text
        namesArray.append(nameLabel)
        let numberOfSets = setsNumber.text?.toInt()
        setsArray.append(numberOfSets!)
        let numberOfReps = repsNumber.text?.toInt()
        repsArray.append(numberOfReps!)


    let detailsEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDetails", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
    let trainingdetails = TrainingDetails(entity: detailsEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
    trainingdetails.exerciseName = exerciseName.text
    trainingdetails.setsNumber = setsNumber.text!
    trainingdetails.repsNumber = repsNumber.text!

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TrainingDay")
    if let fetchResults = moc!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [TrainingDay] {
        daysArray = fetchResults
            let dayLabel = dayName.text
                for day in daysArray {
                    if day == dayLabel {
                    trainingdetails.trainingDay = day
            }
        }
    }

    var error: NSError?
    moc?.save(&error)

    if let err = error {
        var status = err.localizedFailureReason
        println("\(status)")
    } else {
        println("Exercise: #\(exerciseName.text) saved successfully!")
        println("Number of sets: #\(setsNumber.text) saved successfully!")
        println("Number of reps: #\(repsNumber.text) saved successfully!")
    }

    }
```

-> Save exerciseName, setsNumber and repsNumber

Now, this part here:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TrainingDay")
        if let fetchResults = moc!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [TrainingDay] {
            daysArray = fetchResults
                let dayLabel = dayName.text
                    for day in daysArray {
                        if day == dayLabel {
                        trainingdetails.trainingDay = day
                }
            }
        }
```

Why? It’s something like: “Make a fetch. Assign the values of this fetch to daysArray. dayLabel receives what the user printed. Take this variable called “day”, walk through daysArray, if anything in daysArray is equal to dayLabel, which is what the user printed, add it to trainingDay relationship.

For you to know:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class TrainingDay: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var day: String
    @NSManaged var trainingDetails: NSSet

}
```

and

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class TrainingDetails: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var exerciseName: String
    @NSManaged var repsNumber: String
    @NSManaged var setsNumber: String
    @NSManaged var trainingDay: TrainingDay

}
```

When I run the app, this happens:

(entity: TrainingDetails; id: 0xd000000000040002  ; data: {
    exerciseName = "exercise 1";
    repsNumber = 5;
    setsNumber = 2;
    trainingDay = nil;

**trainingDay** is still getting nil! What should I do?

**EDIT 1:**

Code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ExerciseViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //sets stepper configs
        setsStepper.wraps = false
        setsStepper.autorepeat = true
        setsStepper.continuous = true
        setsStepper.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
        setsStepper.minimumValue = 0
        setsStepper.maximumValue = 500
        setsStepper.value = 0

        //reps stepper configs
        repsStepper.wraps = false
        repsStepper.autorepeat = true
        repsStepper.continuous = true
        repsStepper.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        repsStepper.minimumValue = 0
        repsStepper.maximumValue = 500
        repsStepper.value = 0

        exerciseTableView.reloadData()
    }

    var moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?

    @IBOutlet var exerciseTableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var dayName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var exerciseName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var setsStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet var repsStepper: UIStepper!

    @IBOutlet var setsNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var repsNumber: UILabel!

    var daysArray = [TrainingDay]()
    var namesArray = [String]()
    var setsArray = [Int]()
    var repsArray = [Int]()


    func appendTrainingDay() {
        let dayLabel = dayName.text
        let dayEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDay", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
        let newTrainingDay = TrainingDay(entity: dayEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
        newTrainingDay.day = dayName.text

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)

        if let err = error {
            var status = err.localizedFailureReason
            println("\(status)")
        } else {
            println("Training day:\(dayName.text)")
    }
}

    func appendTrainingDetailsToArray () {
        let nameLabel = exerciseName.text
        namesArray.append(nameLabel)
        let numberOfSets = setsNumber.text?.toInt()
        setsArray.append(numberOfSets!)
        let numberOfReps = repsNumber.text?.toInt()
        repsArray.append(numberOfReps!)


        let detailsEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("TrainingDetails", inManagedObjectContext: moc!)
        let trainingdetails = TrainingDetails(entity: detailsEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)
        trainingdetails.exerciseName = exerciseName.text
        trainingdetails.setsNumber = setsNumber.text!
        trainingdetails.repsNumber = repsNumber.text!

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TrainingDay")
        daysArray = (moc!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [TrainingDay])!

        for chosenDay in daysArray {
            println(chosenDay.day)
            if chosenDay == dayName.text {
                println("CHOSEN DAY IS:\(chosenDay)")
                trainingdetails.trainingDay = chosenDay
            }
        }

        var error: NSError?
        moc?.save(&error)

        if let err = error {
            var status = err.localizedFailureReason
            println("\(status)")
        } else {
            println("Exercise: #\(exerciseName.text) saved successfully!")
            println("Number of sets: #\(setsNumber.text) saved successfully!")
            println("Number of reps: #\(repsNumber.text) saved successfully!")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func fixDayButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        appendTrainingDay()
    }


    @IBAction func doneButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        appendTrainingDetailsToArray()
        exerciseTableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func setsStepperAction(sender: UIStepper) {
        println("\(Int(sender.value))")
        setsNumber.text = Int(sender.value).description
    }

    @IBAction func repsStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
        println("\(Int(sender.value))")
        repsNumber.text = Int(sender.value).description
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return namesArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "exerciseCell"
var cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value2, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        }
        let row = indexPath.row
        let name = namesArray[indexPath.row]
        let numberReps = repsArray[indexPath.row]
        let numberSets = setsArray[indexPath.row]
            cell!.textLabel!.text = name
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "Sets: #\(numberSets) Reps: #\(numberReps)"
        return cell!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if chosenDay == dayName.text
```

should be changed to

```
if chosenDay.day == dayName.text
```

Comment: I changed a bit over there. Here: `for chosenDay in daysArray {
            println(chosenDay.day)
            if chosenDay == dayName.text {
                println("CHOSEN DAY IS:\(chosenDay)")
                trainingdetails.trainingDay = chosenDay
            }
        }` the first println(chosenDay.day) shows the days saved in core data. But the if statement seems to be false, the second println doesn't show anything. I wonder; Does it get what is inside the text field? Or do I have to change this logic?

Comment: @NicholasPiccoli is second if is false it is not executed :)

Comment: I know, that's my point, it's not being executed because it's false, it isn't getting what's inside the text field. Do you have any idea on how to solve this? I'm breaking my head on this since weekend.

Comment: What I did not want is if I have the 7 days of the week, create 7 view controllers of which one of them, that's why I'm trying this. Damn!

Comment: @NicholasPiccoli when I asked about source code I was willing to ask if you can upload it to github so that it is possible to run it and understand where the problem is. Otherwise, it is hard to debug it because no one knows what is stored in dayName.text

Comment: AH, ok, I'll upload it, wait a moment!

Comment: @NicholasPiccoli Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87430/discussion-between-andriy-gordiychuk-and-nicholas-piccoli).